# Compare variable from preceding-sibling with current node inside for each loop

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

In foreach loop with xslt 1.0 as you see below sample

```
    <xsl:for-each select="testBanner/banner">

                        <xsl:variable name="messageInDateTime">
                            <xsl:call-template name="dateLessThanTemplate">
                                //Some template logic that returns true or false
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:variable>

                        <boolean><xsl:value-of select="$messageInDateTime" /></boolean>
   </xsl:for-each>
```

Output received

```
<boolean>false</boolean>
<boolean>true</boolean>
<boolean>false</boolean>
```

Is it possible to get the value of `$messageInDateTime` from the previous sibling and apply a condition based on that? something similar to the below

```
 <xsl:if test="$messageInDateTime = 'true'  previous[$messageInDateTime] != 'false' ">
```

I'm able to get the value of a element with previous sibling, but nit sure to get the variable value

Comment: The answer is "Yes, you can, but probably not in the way you are thinking".  But to give a precise answer, you might want to take a step back, and explain exactly what you are trying to achieve (i.e. Why do you need to find the previous sibling, for example), as it might be you don't actually need variables at all. Showing a [Reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) would help. Thanks!

Comment: @TimC The 'dateLessThanTemplate' has a logic  to compare the given time in xml with the server time and returns true or false. Here based on the previous value I would like to show and hide value in the current iteration in for each. is it possible to point me to a sample ? Let me know if yo need more information.